# Using OAuth in Tyrus Web Socket

Tags: java, sockets, oauth, tyrus

I want to set an `OAuth` header like **Authorization: Bearer [oauth token]**. I am trying to use something in the lines of `client.getProperties().put()`. I am unable to come up with the exact syntax. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create and register [ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs-javax.websocket/1.1/javax/websocket/ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator.html). See its [#beforeRequest(...)](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs-javax.websocket/1.1/javax/websocket/ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#beforeRequest(java.util.Map)) method - you can modify handshake request headers there.

Tyrus contains complete unit test for this functionality - see [ModifyRequestResponseHeadersTest.java](https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/blob/master/tests/e2e/standard-config/src/test/java/org/glassfish/tyrus/test/standard_config/ModifyRequestResponseHeadersTest.java).

Also, you can take a look at Tyrus Client Authentication support - you can even define custom authenticator. See [Tyrus User Guide - Client HTTP Authentication](https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.10/user-guide.html#d0e1658); especially chapter 8.14.3.

Comment: i tried using **client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.CREDENTIALS, new Credentials("Authorization", "Bearer key")**  but it doesn't work.

Comment: credentials are just used by registered authenticators. Since Tyrus does not provide one for OAuth, you'll need to implement one; see chapter 8.14.4 for examples of more advanced configuration.

Comment: I tried using
 `AuthConfig authConfig = AuthConfig.Builder.create().
                               disableBasicAuth().
                               build();
  Credentials credentials = new Credentials("Authentication", "Bearer Key");
  client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.AUTH_CONFIG, authConfig);
  client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.CREDENTIALS, credentials);`
But this doesn't work.